# Help constructing regex

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I need to know if a string matches a number of different criterias. I'm trying to solve this by using a regular expression and then see if it matches (in Java: str.matches(myRegex);), but I can't get it right.

The criterias are as follows:

- The string to match is constructed of 4 letters, [A-Z]
- It may be preceeded (but not necessarily) by one of "-", "+" or "VC"
- It shall only match strings containing exactly 4 letters (and the possibly preceeding characters)

Examples:

- "SHSN" -> match
- "+SHRA" -> match
- "VCSHRA" -> match
- "CAVOK" -> no match
- "-+SHSN" -> no match

Is this possible to do in one single regex? Or should it be done in code or a combination of the two?

Thanks,

Linus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^([+-]|VC)?[A-Z]{4}$
```

Comment: +1. But I'd make it a non-capturing group if he doesn't need it to capture: `^(?:[+-]|VC)?[A-Z]{4}$`

Comment: Excellent, thank you!
I'm not familiar with the term "capturing groups" but will look it up.

Comment: @aspartame: The matches of non-capturing groups can not be referenced. So you can’t use `group(1)` to get the match of `(?:[+-]|VC)?`.